# Logging events on java web service

Tags: java, mysql, log4j, tomcat7

I am currently working on a Java Web application that runs on Apache Tomcat 7. Due to the fact that I want to log some information into a database, I use the following configuration file information for initiating my Logger:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cap_recommender_log
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=log_user
log4j.appender.DB.password=some_password
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO notify_service_log(date, logger, level, message) VALUES('%d{YYYY-MM-dd}','%C','%p','%m')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Also, the notify_service_log table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `notify_service_log` ( 
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `logger` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `level` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `message` text NOT NULL,
    KEY `index_level` (`level`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Finally, the web service code is as follows:

```
package com.imis.cap.service.notify;

import com.imis.cap.module.etl.EtlModuleClient;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.ArrayOfServiceMessage;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.BooleanResponse;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.ServiceMessage;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

@WebService(serviceName = "NotifyService", portName = "HttpBinding_NotifyService", endpointInterface = "gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.aia.gr/cap/eventbroker/v1/", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/NotifyService/NotifyService.wsdl")
public class NotifyService {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String log_properties_file;

    private DataSource registration_db;

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger notifyServiceLogger = 
        Logger.getLogger(NotifyService.class);

    public NotifyService() {
        Context context;
        try {
            context = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            this.username = (String) context.lookup("CAP_RECOMMENDER_UNAME");
            this.password = (String) context.lookup("CAP_RECOMMENDER_PASS");
            this.registration_db = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/cap_registration_db");
            this.log_properties_file = (String) context.lookup("NOTIFY_SERVICE_LOG_PROPERTIES_FILE");
        }catch(NamingException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            notifyServiceLogger.error("NotifyService: NamingException occured during construction. Message: " +
                e.getMessage());
        }
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.log_properties_file);
        notifyServiceLogger.info("NotifyService: Object constructor completed successfully.");
   }

   public gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.BooleanResponse notify(gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyRequest request) throws ParseException {
    ArrayOfServiceMessage arrayOfServiceMsg = new ArrayOfServiceMessage();
    ServiceMessage msg = new ServiceMessage();
    BooleanResponse response = new BooleanResponse();
    EventTypeReader eventType = new EventTypeReader(request);
    String regCode = request.getRegistrationCode();
    String dbRegCode = "";
        **notifyServiceLogger.info("NotifyService.notify(): Called with reg-code: " + request.getRegistrationCode() + ".");**

    /**Some more code**/
    return new BooleanResponse(); //Sample response
    }
}
```

The client Code that performs the call of the notify procedure is as follows:

```
package notifyclient;

import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.ArrayOfAttribute;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.BooleanResponse;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.EventType;
import gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyRequest;

public class NotifyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotifyRequest request = new NotifyRequest();
        request.setRegistrationCode("blasdadasd");
        request.setAttributes(new ArrayOfAttribute());
        request.setEventType(EventType.USER);
        BooleanResponse response = notify(request);
        System.out.println("Output: " + response.getErrors().getServiceMessage().toString());
    }

    public static gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.BooleanResponse notify(gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyRequest request) {
        gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyService_Service service = new gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyService_Service();
        gr.aia.cap.eventbroker.v1.NotifyService port = service.getHttpBindingNotifyService();
        return port.notify(request);
    }
}
```

I have to inform you at this point that the required classes that are needed to perform the Web Service call are automatically generated by Netbeans 7.2.

The problem lies on the fact that the Constructor's message is logged into the database, but the information message in the notify function is never logged. Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Comment: Is notify ever called? or is this class just constructed?

Comment: Yes it does. I have developed a test Client in order to perform requests to the web service. The Constructor log message is inserted into the database, but the notify call is not.

Comment: Can you post the client code so we can see it being called in if the issue is in the client not this code?

Comment: I have updated the first post with the requested information. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Any reason for the ** before the call to the logger?

Comment: I tried to use the text formatter of Stackoverflow in order to make this line of code bold. But it did not work. In the actual project these two characters do not exist.

Comment: Try adding `PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.log_properties_file);` before your info logging in that method.  It could be as simple as it needs to be configured before using and its configuration doesn't live outside the scope of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you Lipongo. That made it work. Please post your comment as an answer in order to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments state, adding `PropertyConfigurator.configure(this.log_properties_file);` on the line above the logger call in the `notify()` method resolved the problem.